# ES Query string query with separate unique value check

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

I have a query string query where search is made towards item names from an instant search input field

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "name",
        "query" : "'.$searchQuery.'"
    }
}
}
```

I would however like to include the search for item categories in the same query, hopefully tagged or separated somehow so they can be pushed to the top of the results in the front end. Item categories are in a separate field, _source for single items looks like this,

```
                "_source": {
                "name": "Whatever Item Name",
                "category": "Whatever Category",
```

So if the search input is "Whatever*" it should both be returning items with the name Whatever, but also separately return a list of unique category values which contain "Whatever" (not all items that have "Whatever Category"). So it should be returning items where names match, that can have any category, and also the available categories amongst all items separately. Is this possible to combine in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, but here are the two I would try first.

Use a single query with tagged/named sub-queries. As you can see below, in a `bool/should` we are querying names and categories that match `some_input` with a slight boost on categories so they are ranked best and bubble up in the results. Also, the results are named either `name_match` or `category_match` so you know what kind of hits they are. You might want to play with the boost a little. Also you might need to adjust the size in order to return all the results you expect:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "default_field": "name",
              "query": "some_input",
              "_name": "name_match"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "category": {
              "query": "some_input",
              "boost": 2,
              "_name": "category_match"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query, however, might return the same category several times and some other category not at all, depending on the size you choose. So a better query would be the one below that leverages aggregations for the category part. It will return item matches in the hits section and unique category matches in the aggregation section:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "some_input"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "category": {
            "query": "some_input"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order to compute the categories on all data, you can use [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) instead of `query`:

```
{
  "post_filter": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "some_input"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "category": {
            "query": "some_input"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Second query is exactly what I was looking for. Can however only get it to work for categories that are amongst the categories in the hits. Could it work for all indexed categories, regardless of if they are in the hits or not?

Comment: Awesome, glad it helepd!